# toggle a single elements class eventhough it has multiple instances

Tags: jquery, class, parent-child, multiple-instances, toggleclass

simple thing and i just can't get it to work:

i have several paragraphs that share the same class and i simply want to change one of these classes as their parent div is hovered.

```
<div class="trigger">
   <p class="oldstyle"> some content </p>
/div>

<div class="trigger">
   <p class="oldstyle"> some content </p>
/div>
```

when i hover the first "trigger-div", i want its p to change without affecting the later elements

```
<div class="trigger">
   <p class="newstyle"> some content </p>
/div>

<div class="trigger">
   <p class="oldstyle"> some content </p>
/div>
```

i've got the following code which doesn't work ://

```
$('.trigger').hover(function() {
$(this).next(".oldstyle").toggleClass("newstyle");
});
```

i'm helpless! 
thank's a ton.

Comment: Presumably the typos in `</div>` are typos, and not the source of your error?

Answer (score 3):

Try children since it is not a sibling :

```
$('.trigger').hover(function() {
    $(this).children(".oldstyle").toggleClass("newstyle");
});
```

Comment: thank you so much! this works :) ..
but what exactly is the difference between children and siblings?

Comment: @user3170228 - siblings are elements at the same level on the tree, for example `<div class="item1"></div><div class="item1sibling></div>`, whereas children are items that are nested within that item on the tree, such as `<div class="item1"><div class="item1child"></div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted the existing answer, just thought I'd provide another answer for optimization purposes:

```
$('.trigger').on({
    mouseenter:function(){
        $(this).find('.oldstyle').addClass('newstyle');
    },
    mouseleave:function(){
        $(this).find('.oldstyle').removeClass('newstyle');
    }
});
```

This is a more explicit version of `.hover()` and `.toggleClass()`, I've just had poor experience with `.toggleClass()` firing multiple times if you enter/leave too quickly multiple times, and doing it explicitly like this eliminated that problem. I also used `.find()` instead of `.children()` because generally speaking with small volume of child trees it runs faster than `.children()` because of the lack of "immediate child" verification.