# toggle animation on single instance of multiple classes

Tags: jquery, css, animation, onclick, toggle

with some help from [the community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982530/toggle-a-single-elements-class-eventhough-it-has-multiple-instances) i have managed to address a single instances of a class that occurs more than once without affecting the other classes. thanks!

```
<div class="trigger">
   <p class="mover"> some content </p>
/div>

<div class="trigger">
   <p class="mover"> some content </p>
/div>
```

what i'm now trying to do is to toggle an animation for this single instance.
when "trigger-"div is clicked, i want its child (mover) to move to the right. **this seems to work.**

what **doesn't work** is if i click the next trigger before toggling the previous animation back. the reason is obvious, i guess (the stored variabel is not set back), but i have no clue how to do it.

```
var state="on";
$('.trigger').click(function() {
    if(state == "on"){
         $(this).children(".mover").animate({'margin-right': '-=40px'},'fast'); 
        return state="off";
    } else if(state == "off") {
         $(this).children(".mover").animate({'margin-right': '+=40px'},'fast');
        return state="on";
    }
});
```

thanks alot!

Comment: Can you not assign it an `id`?

Answer (score 0):

Store your `state` in the `.data()` for each individual `.trigger`:

```
$('.trigger').data('state','on').click(function() {
    if($(this).data('state') == "on"){
         $(this).children(".mover").animate({'margin-right': '-=40px'},'fast'); 
        $(this).data('state','off');
    } else if($(this).data('state') == "off") {
         $(this).children(".mover").animate({'margin-right': '+=40px'},'fast');
        $(this).data('state','on');
    }
});
```

or more efficiently:

```
$('.trigger').data('state',true).click(function() {
    if($(this).data('state')){
         $('.mover',this).animate({'margin-right': '-=40px'},'fast'); 
         $(this).data('state',false);
    } else {
         $('.mover',this).animate({'margin-right': '+=40px'},'fast');
         $(this).data('state',true);
    }
});
```